# Turn asynchronous calls to synchronous using GCD, blocks and semaphores

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore, core-bluetooth

I wrote a static library using `CoreBluetooth` framework to connect and exchange data with a Bluetooth Low Energy custom device. Each device has a reference to a `CBPeripheral` instance handled by a `CBPeripheralManager`. For now I'm using the following method to connect to my device after scanning

```
- (void)connectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    // Connects with the peripheral
    [manager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
```

The `connectPeripheral:` method is asynchronous and uses the delegation pattern to perform the proper actions once the connection is established. The developer using my library gets notified about the connection through a notification

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    NSLog(@"Peripheral connected");
    // Start discovering services matching my UUIDs
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BLEDeviceConnected" object:nil];
}
```

This mechanism has a downside: I have to tell the developer using my library the name of the notification so s/he can register to it. I would rather like to build a synchronous method running the `connectPeripheral:` method on another thread and blocking the execution until the device doesn't get connected. In order to achieve that, I would like to use Grand Central Dispatch and, in particular, blocks and semaphores.

Unfortunately these concepts are very hard to understand to me. I started following a tutorial about the subject, but I can't manage to make it work for my needs. So I ask you for some help.

Comment: This is not a trivial question to answer without knowing exactly what happens to what class instance and when.  However I would think you are making a mistake by creating a synchronous method, as the caller will only have to create their own asynchronous mechanism to call yours as they won't want the main thread being blocked.

Comment: @trojanfoe I know, but I would like to export both the async and the sync mechanism.

Comment: My (unanalyzed) knee-jerk reaction is that in trying to turn the intrinsically asynchronous into a synchronous call, you are building a formula for a deadlocked BLE interface. Rather than using a notification, perhaps a delegation scheme would work better. You could call a delegate method or a block your user provides.